# Laravel - validate array to existing array and null

Tags: laravel

Currently making API endpoints for repetition schedule, but I am having an issue in validating array to make sure it exists in the preset array:

For example, the `repeat_day` values must have correct days

This is the API request:

```
{
   "repeat_by": "daily",
   "repeat_day": [
       "Sunday",
       "xxx" 
   ],
   "repeat_date": [],
   "repeat_week": [],
   "repeat_month": []
}
```

This is the `StoreUpdateScheduleRequest`

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->dayArray = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    //and some other array
}

public function rules()
{
    $repeatDayRule = request()->get('repeat_by') == "daily" ? ['required', Rule::in($this->dayArray)] : '';
    //and some other validation rules

    return [
        "repeat_day.*" => $repeatDayRule
        "repeat_date.*" => $repeatDateRule
        "repeat_week.*" => $repeatWeekRule
        "repeat_month.*" => $repeatMonthRule
    ];
}
```

My problem is that, when I provide `null` or empty array, the validation passes which it should fail.

```
{
    "repeat_by": "daily"
    "repeat_day": null //or even []
}
```

---

Note:

- I tried making validation to `request_day` instead of `request_day.*`, but it does not validate the day properly.
- Would like to use Laravel built in validation (maybe I am missing something), and not looking to extend the validation.

---

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement both rules when validating that array with the [`filled`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-filled) rule. Something like this:

```php
return [
    "repeat_day" => 'array|filled',
    "repeat_day.*" => $repeatDayRule,
    "repeat_date" => 'array|filled',
    "repeat_date.*" => $repeatDateRule,
    "repeat_week" => 'array|filled',
    "repeat_week.*" => $repeatWeekRule,
    "repeat_month" => 'array|filled',
    "repeat_month.*" => $repeatMonthRule
];
```

With this code you will check that, for example, `repeat_day` is an **array** and it's **filled**. With the next sentence you will check that its values are valid with the `$repeatDayRule`

Answer (score 0):

'repeat_day' => 'nullable',

insert this inside of your request validation

Comment: The validation should fail, this will cause it to accept null which is already the case at the moment